# EC2, out of memory crash

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I was not able to ssh in to my ec2 instance and had to reboot.

logs shows the following message (`journalctl -b -2 -e`)

```
Jan 12 02:08:03 ip-172-31-20-233 kernel: oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/docker/654b69f95e8c8fc9dde5cf1b6554dfa2ebbd6554bee760c6de410186a3bdfe3d\
,task=java,pid=27444,uid=1000
Jan 12 02:08:03 ip-172-31-20-233 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 27444 (java) total-vm:8005004kB, anon-rss:4744424kB, file-rss:177124kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:10620kB oom_score_adj:0
Jan 12 02:08:03 ip-172-31-20-233 kernel: oom_reaper: reaped process 27444 (java), now anon-rss:4575556kB, file-rss:181220kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

So I guess my system crashed due to out of memory ..

The process which caused the oom was `elasticsearch` server.

What are my options to prevent this type of crash for the future?

I'm running postgresql and elasticsearch on this machine for a web service.

I'm using `t3-large`.

1. I can think of separating `elasticsearch` to it's own server.. (and possibly multiple nodes of ES, which means multiple EC2 for `elasticsearch` service)
2. I can go up `t3-xlarge`
3. I can switch to more memory focused instance? `R5` type instance?

Are there other options?
I have a hunch that `#1` might be the most recommended way of thinking.. Am I correct?

Comment: It is [recommended](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup.html#dedicated-host) to run elasticsearch in production as the only service in the server, so I would try the first option, but other issues can lead to OOM crashes, like the number of shards and their sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its a production system or if you are trying to build one, you should definitely run it in a Cluster where different nodes of ES have different roles (data note, master node, Load balancer) etc.

You should also take care of how much amount of data you would be pushing, retrieving, indexing, and choosing your AWS hardware and memory accordingly.